# How can I get my nav bar to center?

Tags: html, css

```html
<! doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to page 1 - Home</title>
    <link href="style/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</al></li>
            <li><a href="#">Back-end</al></li>
            <li><a href="#">Web design</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</al></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CSS</al></li>
                    <li><a href="#">JS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="header">
    </div>

    <div id="navbar">
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <p>Viverra hac torquent ultricies lectus tempor. Posuere aliquet adipiscing vulputate tempus class placerat fames placerat. Nam magna ultricies per velit velit scelerisque proin netus, natoque. Magnis suscipit porttitor vel. Venenatis conubia duis natoque elementum netus tellus. In ridiculus a sagittis turpis eu ornare et, eros laoreet ad aliquet aliquet. Dapibus varius, nam vehicula Vestibulum nostra sodales maecenas vulputate tempor libero aliquam. Feugiat litora et. Faucibus turpis justo lacus commodo sociosqu litora euismod pharetra ullamcorper malesuada sollicitudin natoque vehicula tristique curabitur neque morbi, convallis at nam gravida feugiat feugiat nunc sit.

Nam. Tristique odio ut litora condimentum aptent, senectus consectetuer. Hendrerit suscipit volutpat fames, vehicula arcu. Pellentesque rhoncus libero varius quam fames. Id sollicitudin tincidunt cras cum maecenas lorem, feugiat metus. Montes. Sociosqu hymenaeos class dis et turpis ornare ipsum.
        </p>
    </div>
```

```css
 body   {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #9c9f84;
    font-family: verdana, gerorgia, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.container {
}

ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
}

ul li {
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 120px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    line-height: 30px;
    list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
}

#header {
    background-color: #5c755e;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#navbar {
    background-color: #5c755e;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.main {
    background-color: #e5e4d7;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 110%;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 110%;
    color: purple;
}
```

I've been having trouble trying to center my nav bar and lower my content. I tried using float: left; but it's not working, but it still floats right. Is it because of my list elements that's keeping them from centering? What can I do to prevent this and also lower the paragraph and header text. Also, my dropdown under web design is white, how can I change this? Would I have to change it to the color of the background I'm using under li hover?

Comment: Your html code is totally wrong. There are tags without close character `>`

Comment: You have closing, but not opening ``</al>`` tags...

Comment: http://jsbin.com/biyalulize/edit?html,css,output

added class for parent container of navbar (`.navbar-con`) and navbar (`.navbar`). added css for two classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: #9c9f84;
  font-family: verdana, gerorgia, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.container {}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 120px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

ul li ul {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

#header {
  background-color: #5c755e;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #5c755e;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.main {
  background-color: #e5e4d7;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 110%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 110%;
  color: purple;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/112/)**